# So, how localized does it have to be to be TOO localized?

Tags: discussion, closing

[Billare mentioned in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15803/good-public-dedicated-call-of-duty-servers-list-for-players-in-india-please) that Jeff and Joel made the distinction between a localized and *too* localized.

To hear it:

> Start 24:45 of the Soundclound podcast [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/podcast-88/); it's streaming and fast-forwardable (so there's no transcript available.) Joel recapitulates the same feelings, in more depth, starting at 57:17.

The thing is, the "too localized" close reason is:

> This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

The mentioned question is only applicable to a specific geographic area *and* a specific moment in time; but that geographic area is *huge* and the "moment in time" can last months. Localized? Yes. **Too** localized and close-worthy? I don't know. I still *think* so, but what do others think?

Comment: Honestly, if I close a question as too localized, it was probably not worth keeping around and this was just the best excuse I could find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the blog

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

> **It is OK to edit a question to make it more general.** With the power of editing comes the power to take someone’s selfish, very specific question, and edit it a little bit until they’re asking the more general question that hundreds of people encounter. For example, if someone asks, “I set up a web server at home but I can’t access it from work,” it’s OK to rewrite the question as, “What things should I check when a web server running at home is not visible on the Internet?” In fact, sometimes selfish, stupid questions of the “do my homework” variety can be easily edited into a form where the answer will provide an extremely valuable resource for the internet at large.

Comment: It seems like by the time you can get around to editing it, there are a few close votes, which reinforce any *hint* of subjectivity to the point where it cannot stay open.

Answer (score 2):

To emphasize, 95% of the time when I vote to close as 'too localized' it is because said questions are usually relevant only for a brief **time**.  Google something like "is world of warcraft down" and you'll get results like this: "[Is world of warcraft down right now? - Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110304010415AAcHCs7)", or "when will portal 2 be released" for "[Answers.com - When will portal 2 be released?](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/When_will_portal_2_be_released)".  Pages like those really irk me when I flip through them, and I don't want to see GSE be filled with those questions.

For the question at-hand, answering with a list of servers is *terrible*, as they come and go all the time.  There should be no *expectation* that someone will routinely "maintain" an answer, though it does happen from time to time as games (SC2, Minecraft, Die2Nite) are updated.

A better answer would be to post a link to a page that routinely updates good servers in the asker's region.  Is this good enough?  Maybe.  I'd like to see some sort of description about how one would come across it rather than a URL and nothing else.  The question should then read differently though, to prevent new users from stumbling across the question and simply posting their favorite server of the day.  Said posts *would answer the question* (as it is now), but I don't want them here.